# GIT SHA id of a file on remote git branch

Tags: git, commit, sha

I would like to know if there is any command available to get the SHA id of a particular file on a given specific git branch on the GIT remote server?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply..

I got below command working to meet my scenario for now.. but trying to see if there is any direct command to find the latest ID of a file on remote server...

> git log 'branch-name' -- 'file-name'

which displaying log messages with ID, Author and Date.. I am fetching the top first line with unix pipe head command.

> git log 'branch-name' -- 'file-name' | head -1

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing additional informations in answer (which it's not)

Answer (score 2):

[git lsremote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) is one of the few commands running against a remote repo, as explained in "[Show git logs for range of commits on remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958905/show-git-logs-for-range-of-commits-on-remote-server)".
But it will only display SHA1 on refs (tags, branches, ...), not a specific file.

For a file, you need first to **[fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)** the remote repo, and then you can [query your information on a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git).