# Run `git log` on a remote branch

Tags: git, github

I want the output of `git log` of a git repository but I don't want to have to clone the entire repository.

I.e. I want something semantically like the following

`git log git@github.com:username/reponame.git`

If there is a way to do this I'll also want the same for `git whatchanged`

If github provides a simple solution for this I would be willing to restrict myself to only git repositories hosted on github.

Comment: I think that would go against git being a *distributed* vcs, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show git logs for range of commits on remote server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958905/show-git-logs-for-range-of-commits-on-remote-server)

Comment: Duplicate of [Commit history on remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13941976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is to just look at the history on the github.com website. If you need `git log` to work from the command-line then you need your own clone of the repository.

In theory you could write a command-line tool that pulls down commit information from github's API, but this would be restricted to showing just commit messages/metadata, and not actual diffs.

Answer (score 8):

You should fetch the remote branch then interact with it. `git fetch` will pull the remote branch into your local repository's FETCH_HEAD, but not your working directory.

`git log FETCH_HEAD --decorate=full` will let you see where your HEAD is in comparison to refs/origin/HEAD, which is the remote branch.

`git whatchanged FETCH_HEAD --decorate=full` is the same as above, but also shows the files that have changed.

`git diff HEAD FETCH_HEAD` diffs between your repository's HEAD and the remote branch's HEAD that you just fetched

`git diff --stat HEAD FETCH_HEAD` a summary preview of the changes, just as you would see during the merge and at the bottom of a git pull.

Note that if you do wish to pull in the fetched changes, just do a `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. (When you `git pull` you are essentially just doing a fetch then a merge)

Comment: This answer is useless wrg of the actual question asked, but I give it an upvote anyway as it solved the problem I wanted to solve when duckduckgoing for "git log remote branch" :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do a shallow clone, which would limit the amount of stuff you'd have to fetch if you only need the recent history:

```
git clone --depth 100 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found two ways of doing this with GitHub:

1. Use the web API to query the log information (not trivial but doable)
2. Use "svn log", since GitHub now partially emulates an SVN server on the Git repositories

Answer (score -1):

The Unix way is to have a shell account:

```
ssh user@otherserver cd reponame.git '&&' git log
```

and

```
ssh user@otherserver cd reponame.git '&&' git whatchanged
```

This method has the advantage of running whatever you want on the remote server. I doubt this will work with github though.