# Commit history on remote repository

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to access a branch's commit history on a remote repository. I had a look at [the doc](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) but could not find any substantial information on how to access a remote repo's commit history using my local git client.

Comment: `lg2 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all`  I don't know where I get this, but It works for me

Answer (score 341):

```
git log remotename/branchname
```

Will display the log of a given remote branch in that repository, but only the logs that you have "fetched" from their repository to your personal "copy" of the remote repository.

Remember that your clone of the repository will update its state of any remote branches only by doing `git fetch`. You can't connect directly to the server to check the log there, what you do is download the state of the server with `git fetch` and then locally see the log of the remote branches.

Perhaps another useful command could be:

```
git log HEAD..remote/branch
```

which will show you the commits that are in the remote branch, but not in your current branch (`HEAD`).

Comment: "You can't connect directly to the server to check the log there" - that was the issue I was having

Comment: I'm only getting local pulled changes... note the remote ones, even doing fetch before.

Comment: When doing a `git fetch` you need to use `--all` to fetch from remotes.

Comment: That's too bad, so I have to clone 2GB worth of objects just to look through the commit logs?

Comment: I just verified this by running the command on a repo I knew I was locally behind on; the first entry returned reflected the latest commit remotely

Comment: Hi @TWiStErRob you can mitigate pain by managing the amount of data fetched with a shallow clone (see --depth in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), then manage fetches with  (see "shallow" in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Comment: This answer was helpful, and then https://stackoverflow.com/a/31625264/470749 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414393/470749 added more helpful information too.

Answer (score 81):

NB. "origin" below use to represent the upstream of a cloned repository, replace "origin" with a descriptive name for the remote repo. "remote reference" can use the same format used in clone command.

```
git remote add origin <remote reference>
git fetch
git log origin/master
```

Comment: what is remote reference here?

Comment: @user1795998 The remote repository Git URL, e.g. `git://git.somedomain.tld/some/repo`

Comment: Don't you need to specify `<refspec>` when fetching (or use `fetch --all`) if you're not tracking any branch on the remote?

Comment: @all - lets ay I want to fetch from git URL:https://git.qrepo.com from branch "master" and project "vendor/diag" ,what would be the commands?

Comment: What do you mean with "project vendor/diag"? Is that a folder inside the repository? Another branch?

Comment: @LopSae - a repository has multiple projects and branches..vendor/diag is another project,I still cant get these commands to work

Comment: A repository can have multiple branches, but "project" is not a term related to git, from there the confusion to what a "project" means in this case. Still, what would that have to do with the question?

Comment: I don't believe its possible to do this in GIT. You must clone that remote repository before you can issue a git log against it.

Answer (score 52):

I'm not sure when filtering was added but it's a way to exclude the object blobs if you only want to fetch the history/ref-logs:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --single-branch --branch master git://some.repo.git .
git log
```

Comment: This is *perfect*. Given the other answers, it would be awesome if this were able to stand out next to the provided answer.

Comment: You deserve 20 stars for this....

Comment: Also, since you are checking out a specific branch you can also add --filter=tree:0  to exclude other branch trees.  Adding tree:0 was 75% smaller than without.

Answer (score 20):

A fast way of doing this is to clone using the `--bare` keyword and then check the log:

```
git clone --bare git@giturl tmpdir
cd tmpdir
git log branch
```

Answer (score 16):

This is what worked for me:

```
git fetch --all 
git log production/master
```

Note that this fetches from ALL remotes, i.e. potentially you ["have to clone 2GB worth of objects just to look through the commit logs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/commit-history-on-remote-repository#comment60695863_13944180).

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe this is possible. I believe you have to clone that remote repo locally and perform `git fetch` on it before you can issue a `git log` against it.

Comment: imagine you already clone the repo to local and make some changes . . then you want to check if anyone has committed to the remote repo

Comment: If you change this answer to "It is not possible" then this is the best answer.  There is no way to access a remote repo's commit history using a remote git client.

Answer (score 13):

You can only view the log on a local repository, however that can include the fetched branches of all remotes you have set-up.

So, if you clone a repo...

```
git clone git@gitserver:folder/repo.git
```

This will default to `origin/master`.

You can add a remote to this repo, other than `origin` let's add `production`. From within the local clone folder:

```
git remote add production git@production-server:folder/repo.git
```

If we ever want to see the log of `production` we will need to do:

```
git fetch --all
```

This fetches from ALL remotes (default fetch without `--all` would fetch just from `origin`)

After fetching we can look at the log on the `production` remote, you'll have to specify the branch too.

```
git log production/master
```

All options will work as they do with log on local branches.

Answer (score 3):

`git` isn't a centralized scm like `svn` so you have two options:

- Use the web interface of target platforms (f.e. [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest) or [GitLab REST API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/api_resources.html))
- Download the repository and display logs locally

It may be annoying to implement for many different platforms (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, SourceForge, Launchpad, Gogs, ...) but fetching data is pretty slow (we talk about seconds) - no solution is perfect.

---

An example with fetching into a temporary directory:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.git -b master --depth 3 --bare --filter=blob:none -q .
git log -n 3 --no-decorate --format=oneline
```

Alternatively:

```sh
git init --bare -q
git remote add -t master origin https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.git
git fetch --depth 3 --filter=blob:none -q
git log -n 3 --no-decorate --format=oneline origin/master
```

Both are optimized for performance by restricting to exactly 3 commits of one branch into a minimal local copy without file contents and preventing console outputs. Though opening a connection and calculating deltas during *fetch* takes some time.

---

An example with GitHub:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/rust-lang/rust/commits?sha=master&per_page=3
```

An example with GitLab:

```
GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/inkscape%2Finkscape/repository/commits?ref_name=master&per_page=3
```

Both are really fast but have different interfaces (like every platform).

---

*Disclaimer: Rust and Inkscape were chosen because of their size and safety to stay, no advertisement*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash function that makes it easy to view the logs on a remote. It takes two optional arguments. The first one is the **branch**, it defaults to **master**. The second one is the **remote**, it defaults to **staging**.

```
git_log_remote() {
  branch=${1:-master}
  remote=${2:-staging}
  
  git fetch $remote
  git checkout $remote/$branch
  git log
  git checkout -
}
```

examples:

```
 $ git_log_remote
 $ git_log_remote development origin
```

Comment: Why are you doing `git checkout $remote/branch ; git log ; git checkout -`. Wouldn't just `git log $remote/branch` work here?

Comment: @MichaelFirth I just checked and indeed it would. Knowing that really make the helper function obsolete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for remote branches that contained a particular commit

here's a quick script you can use as an example

```
spark 
✦ ❯ cat run.sh
for b in $(git branch -r)
do

    hasKryoCommit=$(git log "$b" | grep 3e033035a3c0b7d46c2ae18d0d322d4af3808711)
    if test -n "$hasKryoCommit"
    then
        echo "$b"
    fi
done

spark 
✦ ❯ bash run.sh
origin/HEAD
fatal: unrecognized argument: ->
origin/master
origin/branch-2.4
origin/branch-3.0
origin/branch-3.1
origin/branch-3.2
origin/master
```