# Check commits done by others on git

Tags: git

My teammate has pushed some code changes on the git repo but when I use the command git log, I cannot see his commit in the commit history. I can view it only when I pull the code. Is there a way to see all the commits made by everyone without pulling the code using git pull.

Comment: Duplicate of [git log command to check for commit history on remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/git-log-command-to-check-for-commit-history-on-remote-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster asks:

> Is there a way to see all the commits made by everyone without pulling the code using git pull.

The answer is **no**. In order to see a log of the newest changes on the remote repository, ***you must fetch or pull*** those changes first:

```
git fetch origin
git log origin/master
```

Or

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git log origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [check the log on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/git-log-command-to-check-for-commit-history-on-remote-server) instead of your local using `git log remote remotename/branchname`. For example:

```
git log remote origin/master
```

Comment: `git log remote` isn't an actual git command. There is a `git log --remotes` flag, but that won't make a network operation to find out if the remote has new commits. You still need to fetch or pull first.

Answer (score 1):

To see what commits have been added to the upstream , you can run a git log using  branch with the following commands:

```
git log origin/<branch>
```

More info: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/remote-repositories#!fetch

Comment: The original poster is asking if there is a way to view new commits on a remote without having to fetch or pull. Your answer still requires a fetch or pull if there are new commits, so it doesn't really solve the problem.