# How to get git to display the most recent n commits from all online branches

Tags: git, github

I am new to GIT. I have a repository on git hub.com. I committed a new file to github repository. When I check the last commit changes using `log` command it shows only the commits on my local repository. But my github repository is a collaborative repository. The question is that I have to check recent commits if others commits a file. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commit history on remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/commit-history-on-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Once you `fetch` the remote repository, you have all the commits in your local repo. You also have the branches of the remote repo: they're just prefixed with `origin/` (if your remote is called origin). You can list them with `git branch -r`

So you can do something like this:

```
git fetch origin
N=3 #say you want to see the last 3 commits of each remote branches
for REMOTE_BRANCH in $(git branch -r | grep origin); do
  echo "Showing branch $REMOTE_BRANCH"
  git log -$N $REMOTE_BRANCH
done
```

That is if you want to stick to command line. Otherwise it might be easier to use gitk:

```
sudo apt-get install gitk #Or any other way to install it depending on your platform
git fetch
gitk --all # flag --all implies "show every branches"
```