# How to get all the statistics for a Github repository using the API?

Tags: python, git, api, github, github-api

I want to achieve something like `git log --stat` achieves using the Github API.

I want to get all the commits that occurred in a repository along with the files that were changed in that particular commit.

How should I go about doing this with the Github API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commit history on remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/commit-history-on-remote-repository)

Comment: No, not really. Github has its own privacy setting. It's not technically a remote-git host.

Comment: The security settings are implemented in protocol level. There is nothing special about GitHub as a remote host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First grab the commits from `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:project/commits`

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/masnun/torrent-tweeter/commits
```

Then you can use the commits API to get the changed files. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit