# getting information about commits of remote branches [Git]

Tags: git, ls-remote

Question about Git:

For a remote project, I would like to get it's last commit information (the last commit date) of a specific branch, without doing a clone.

I saw that I can use the following command `git ls-remote --heads ssh:<path>` in order to get all the branches. Using awk I can get the following list of branches:

```
BranchA
BranchB
BranchC
```

for each branch, I would like to get the date of the last commit, without doing a clone. Is it even possible? if no, what other alternative ways there are in order to get the information about all branches and their last commit date.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. you can use `-bare` flag to avoid cloning entire repo. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414393/3276830

Comment: @VarunGarg I thought bare does clone the entire repo, it just doesn't have a work tree.

Comment: Doesn't `ls-remote` give you commit IDs as well as names?

Comment: @evolutionbox it does but how can it help me to get the last commit date?