# How to query git logs at git server?

Tags: git

I know I can use

> git log

to query logs at local.

But I want to execute a linux command at git server'repository to query logs.

Is there such a similar command I can use at git server?

Comment: `git fetch && git log origin/<branch>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commit history on remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/commit-history-on-remote-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to log in to the server by ssh, you can use `ssh` to run `git log`.

Suppose the repository in the server is at `/path/to/foo.git`.

```
ssh ${user}@${server_ip} git --git-dir=/path/to/foo.git log ${branch}
```

Comment: This help me. I use ' git --git-dir=/path/to/foo.git log ' at git sever' repo and it is success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first update the remote-tracking branches and then check the log:

```
git fetch && git log origin/<branch> --name-status --pretty=...
```

Read more about [`git-fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to execute a linux command at git server to query logs directly.Your idea is also a good one.